# Height values for each point in a plot

Tags: r, data-visualization, scatter-plot, kernel-density

I have a data of protein-protein interactions in a data  frame entitled: s1m. Each DB and AD pair make an interaction and I can plot it as well:

```
> head(s1m)
     DB_num AD_num
[1,]      2   8153
[2,]      7   3553
[3,]      8   4812
[4,]     13   7838
[5,]     24   3315
[6,]     24   6012
```

Plot of the data looks like:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/RTaeJ5r.jpg]

I then used code I found on this site to plot filled contour lines:

```
## compute 2D kernel density, see MASS book, pp. 130-131
require(MASS)
z <- kde2d(s1m[,1], s1m[,2], n=50)
plot(s1m, xlab="X label", ylab="Y label", pch=19, cex=.4)
filled.contour(z, drawlabels=FALSE, add=TRUE)
```

It gave me the resulting image(minus the scribbles):
[image: result]

MY QUESTION: I need to annotate each line of data in the original `s1m` data frame with a number corresponding to its height on the contour map (hence my scribbles on the image above). I think the list z has the values I am looking for, but I am not sure.

In the end I would want my data to hopefully look something like this so I could study the protein interactions in groups:

```
         DB_num AD_num   height
    [1,]      2   8153        1
    [2,]      7   3553        1
    [3,]      8   4812        3
    [4,]     13   7838        6
    [5,]     24   3315        2
    [6,]     24   6012        etc.
```

Comment: When you attach the value 1, 2, 3, etc to each combination of `DB_num` and `AD_num` are those dummy numbers referring to the actual density or the bin into which it's density falls. In other words, is 2 on your plot referring to the actual value 2 or to the 2nd bin (which takes values 1e-9 to 1.5e9?

Comment: Since `contour.plot` seems not to return useful values, I suppose this involves two issues that are a bit tricky: (i) mapping from the values in `s1m` to the lattice-like coordinates used by the contour plot, and (ii) reproducing the levels assigned in the different positions of the grid; granted, that is some kind of bricolage, but (ii) can maybe be achieved by borrowing and invoking `contour.plot`'s own syntax, e.g. `levels <- cut(as.numeric(z$z),pretty(range(z$z),20))`, or computing levels yourself and setting the corresponding parameter explicitly...

Comment: @GavinSimpson The dummy numbers would be referring to the bin, but the having the actual values of the points would probably work too.

Comment: Maybe what you need is contour lines? http://www.r-bloggers.com/fix-overplotting-with-colored-contour-lines/

Comment: @texb - I'm not sure what you mean. I just started using R. How would I match the values in the grid (stored in 'levels' I think) to the individual points? Or how would I compute the "density" of each point explicitly?

Comment: @Roman Luštrik The graph produced is fine, I need the data that goes along with the graph annotated to the points. Is there some way to match the points with the 'height' of the contour line they are in?

Comment: @KerpalJenkiens OK, thanks for confirmation. I've added something now which should get you 99.9% of the way there.

Comment: @texb +1 you are pretty much there, only missing thing is to point to the component `z` of the object returned by `kde2d()` to give the actual `heights` used in the plot, *before grouping*.

Comment: @KerpalJenkiens I missed the need to work with the actual data, not the points the KDE was evaluated at.

Answer (score 3):

This is one option if you want the actual height not the bin each is assigned to

```
## dummy data
DF <- data.frame(DB_num = rnorm(10000), AD_num = rnorm(10000))

require("MASS")

kde <- kde2d(DF[,1], DF[,2], n = 50)
```

Note the `kde2d` returns as component `z` which is a matrix with (in this case) 50 rows and columns where rows correspond to the `x` data and columns to the `y` data. As a matrix is just a vector, and the data are filled by columns, we can exploit this and stack the `x` and `y` values `n` times each (`n = 50` here), then unwind `kde$z`

```
dd <- dim(kde$z)
res <- data.frame(DB_num = rep(kde$x, times = dd[1]),
                  AD_num = rep(kde$y, times = dd[2]),
                  height = as.numeric(kde$z))
```

This produces

```
> head(res)
        DB_num      AD_num                                  height
1 -3.582508378 -3.79074271 0.0000000000000000000000000006907447484
2 -3.429230262 -3.63682706 0.0000000000000000000000002951259863229
3 -3.275952146 -3.48291141 0.0000000000000000000000558203373144190
4 -3.122674029 -3.32899576 0.0000000000000000000055565720524140235
5 -2.969395913 -3.17508011 0.0000000000000000014967010810961022503
6 -2.816117797 -3.02116446 0.0000000000000008159370528768207499471
```

To get the bins, you'd need to follow what `filled.contour` did, which is to form breaks via

```
nlevels <- 20 ## default
brks <- pretty(range(res$height), nlevels)

> brks
 [1] 0.00 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.07 0.08 0.09 0.10 0.11 0.12 0.13 0.14
[16] 0.15 0.16
```

Then use `cut` to assign each `height` to a bin on basis of `brks`, something like

```
res <- transform(res, bin = as.numeric(cut(height, brks)))
```

Which gives

```
> head(res)
        DB_num      AD_num                                  height bin
1 -3.582508378 -3.79074271 0.0000000000000000000000000006907447484   1
2 -3.429230262 -3.63682706 0.0000000000000000000000002951259863229   1
3 -3.275952146 -3.48291141 0.0000000000000000000000558203373144190   1
4 -3.122674029 -3.32899576 0.0000000000000000000055565720524140235   1
5 -2.969395913 -3.17508011 0.0000000000000000014967010810961022503   1
6 -2.816117797 -3.02116446 0.0000000000000008159370528768207499471   1
```

You'll probably want to check the details of `?cut` to determine behaviour on the boundary of a bin, but that should get you close enough.

Comment: @texb I don't think that is going to work well. It would be better to use a tool that returned enough things to allow for predictions at the actual values observed. I think something in the **kernsmooth** package would be ideal. Let me look. (and yes, I missed the line about wanting to tie each observation in the original data).

Comment: Actually, scratch that, **KernSmooth** does exactly the same as `kde2d()` with its function `bkde2D()`

Comment: @texb In lieu of that, I think your addition is probably the easiest thing to do at this stage. +1

Comment: First of all, very clever answers, but @textb I tried using your method and I am not sure that it is placing the points into accurate bins. Using a random set of points, I used the Gavin's method and annotated the DF list. I then looked at where some of the points were falling by eye, and some seemed off. I didn't know how to markup the filled.contour graphic so I made another one for proof of concept. I don't the point marked by the lines should be in that high of a bin: http://i.imgur.com/63H9RZC.png

Comment: @KerpalJenkiens The real issue is that you want something to predict the `height` as you would be reading off the plot, when neither `kde2d` nor `filled.contour` allow this. `kde2d` is just evaluating the density at 50x50 evenly spaced locations and `filled.contour` is finding contours and filling the regions between them. I'm looking for a 2D KDE that will return estimates of the density at the observed values. It would be best to use such a thing, assuming it exists!

Comment: @KerpalJenkiens: There is certainly an element of tinkering about it; maybe one useful intermediate step would be to (graphically) ensure that the identification of the nearest grid elements works as intended (e.g. like `mat <- expand.grid((s <- seq(0,1,.2)),s); image(outer(s,s,"^")); new.obs <- data.frame(runif(8),runif(8)); nearest <- apply(new.obs,1,function(x) which.min((x[1]-mat[,1])**2+(x[2]-mat[,2])**2)); arrows(new.obs[,1],new.obs[,2],mat[nearest,1],mat[nearest,2])`), and potentially querying the folks at [stats.stackexchange.com] about the general approach might also be an idea.

Comment: @KerpalJenkins: I had to delete my original comment about complementing `s1m` with with some meaningful density estimate 'in the vicinity' of the observation, because it seemed to contain some faulty bracketing (which probably produced the errors shown in your graphic); sorry. I hope this works better: `which.min.d <- function(x1,y1,x2,y2) which.min((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2); DF$height <- apply(DF,1,function(x) res[which.min.d(x[1],x[2],res$DB_num,res$AD_num),"height"])`, but still recommend visualizing results e.g. by using `arrows` as demonstrated above...

Comment: Okay, I've tried using the approach listed in the original answer by @GavinSimpson, and it seems that the bins listed in `res` do not match up when I checked a few by hand. Therefore, I am guessing that trying to annotate `DF` would be futile if `res` is wrong. It was a noble attempt, but if it cannot be done, it's alright since my research has shifted to a different method anyway.

Comment: not sure if `res <- data.frame(DB_num = rep(kde$x, times = dd[1]), AD_num = rep(kde$y, times = dd[2]), etc` is correct here - you're just repeating every coordinate 50 times. I think it should be that the y coordinates need to be repeated with `each = ...`: `data.frame(DB_num = rep(kde$x, times = dd[1]), AD_num = rep(kde$y, each = dd[2]), ...)`